# Mathoverflow for finding the name of mathematical concepts

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I am used to posting on MathOverflow problems with questions. However, now I am looking for the name of a mathematical object that I think already exists (and I would be happy to find reference recommendations about it).

Is MathOverflow appropriate for such questions, although I am not asking to discuss any (research) problem/solution?

Comment: You could have a look on the main site among the questions tagged ([tag:terminology]) - to see whether some of them are similar to your question - and how they were received.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes, such questions can certainly be on topic,** providing they meet the usual criteria for good questions.

Theoretical answer: The general primary criterion is that a question should be *about research-level mathematics* — and asking for previous literature one some mathematical object is certainly about research-level mathematics (provided the object isn’t something extremely well-known, trivial, etc.)  See also the reasoning in the answers/comments of [Should this site be "a shortcut to substitute for literature searches"?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1516/should-this-site-be-a-shortcut-to-substitute-for-literature-searches) — most of that applies here too, in particular about how to draw the line of what makes something “research-level”.

Practical answer: I’ve had [several](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54377/does-this-flipping-lexicographic-ordering-have-a-standard-name) [such](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296349/terminology-product-on-strict-preorders-corresponding-to-direct-product-of-preo) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326377/terminology-a-certain-semicategory-with-objects-morc-not-the-usual-or-twiste) [positively-received](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228364/pronunciation-of-inverted-exclamation-mark-historically-used-for-subfactoria).