# What should I do if I believe to found the answer to my question but I'm not sure?

Tags: discussion

Four months ago I asked [one question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408130/what-functions-do-we-need-to-solve-linear-second-order-differential-equations-wi) in MO and had no expected answer. After following the clues from comments of other users I realized that, in that time, I didn't even know how to properly ask what I wanted to know.
Now, four months and a lot of reading later, I believe that I know how to ask properly what I had in mind and also that I had already found the answer, but I'm not sure if this answer is correct.

My question is: What should I do?

What come to my mind is to open a new post stating the proper form of the question and asking if my answer is correct. Is this the best to do?

Ps: I have searched for this and had no results. I found [this post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/730/answering-my-own-question) and [this post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1338/answer-your-own-question-share-your-knowledge-qa-style-is-there-consensus) about answering your own question, but it's not my case as I'm not sure if the answer is correct. I also found [this question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1265/using-math-overflow-to-check-whether-or-not-a-proof-is-correct) and [this question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3510/is-there-a-clear-rule-against-check-this-proof-type-questions?rq=1) about using MO for "proof checking", but this is not my case either.

**Edit:** [Here is a link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418303/about-writing-solutions-of-linear-odes-is-this-statement-correct) to the post created from this.

Comment: Hmm. My first instinct is to edit the first question to include the cleaned-up version at the top (keeping the old version clearly delineated at the bottom, so the comments make sense). But you could instead ask a new question, linking to the old question and vice versa (and ask a mod to close the old one, for example as no longer relevant). This latter option seems desirable given the length of the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your help dear @DavidRoberts! I will follow you second option.